# Rails 4.0 image_tag custom attributes

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4

When I include the optional tags within image_tag it throws an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `src' for #<#<Class:0x007fa143339230>:0x007fa147942998>
```

Original HTML (or desired)

```
<img src="dark-logo.png" data-src="dark-logo.png" data-src-retina="logo-retina.png" width="244" height="56" alt="">
```

Rails View

```
<%= image_tag "dark-logo.png", data-src => "dark-logo.png %>
```

How do I get the optional Tags in image_tag to render the desired HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag "dark-logo.png", data: { src: "dark-logo.png", src_retina: "logo.png" } %>
```

It's mentioned in the [Rails API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag), but a bit hard to find.

Inside the `data` hash, any `-` should be replaced by a `_`, since Ruby doesn't like a `-` as part of a variable name.

Comment: How would you do it to include data-src-retina="logo-retina.png" ?

Comment: I know this answer is old, but is there a way to add `data: { src: image_tag 'dark-logo.png' }` so it goes to the assets folder automatically?